# move onclick function to other element with jquery - reading attr() returns function

Tags: jquery, regex, function, onclick, call

I have an `<img src="blabla.png" onclick="someFunction();">` tag that I want to replace with an `<a>` tag (created dynamically).

I want to move the onclick from the  to the  but when I read `attr("onclick")` it returns:

```
function onclick(event) {
  someFunction();
}
```

How can I extract only the `someFunction();` call and set this to the onclick of the `<a>` tag?

After the answer I used it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".content img[src*=images]").each(function(){
        $(this).after("<a href=# class='button'></a>");
        $(this).next().text($(this).attr("alt"));
        $(this).next().click(this.onclick);
        /* remove old img */
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `this.onclick` instead of $(this).attr('onclick'). It will be a function type and you can simply set the `a.onclick = img.onclick`.

Ideally however the image would have a click handler and would be bound unobtrusively.

```
var someFunction = function(){};
$('img').click(someFunction);
```

Then you could use the same function on the a

```
$('a').click(someFuncion);
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my post using your answer. It seems to work :)